# How to change Muti-Task Page Title in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I changed app title with the below code in Android Manifest.xml, but I can't change the app name on the multi-tasking screen.

```dart
    <application
        android:label="WCC"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the title in `MaterialApp`.

```dart
MaterialApp(title: appName);
```

In your case it should be

```dart
MaterialApp(title: "Flutter Demo");
```